# Provisioning AWS Amplify using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-amplify

I am trying to provision the AWS amplify using Terraform and when I do terraform init and terraform plan there is no error but when applying (terraform apply) it is giving me error

> Error: creating Amplify App (nextjs_app_amplify): BadRequestException: You should at least provide one valid token with aws_amplify_app.nextjs_app, on main.tf line 7, in resource aws_amplify_app" "nextjs_app": 7: resource "aws_amplify_app" "nextjs_app" {

**This is only message is printing**

*My Main.tf file*

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "ap-south-1"
  access_key = "xxxxx"
  secret_key = "xxxxx"
}

resource "aws_amplify_app" "nextjs_app" {
    name     = "nextjs_app_amplify"
    platform = "WEB"
    repository = "https://github.com/xxx/nectjs-example.git"
    }
```

Note:- My repo is Public repo.

Comment: There is a note in the documentation about the error you are referencing. And here's the section you need to read through: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/amplify_app#repository-with-tokens.

Comment: Yes, that solves my problem, Just need to create a auth token on my github and use it in my main.tf file. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new Amplify App with the `repository` argument, you also need to set `oauth_token` or `access_token` for authentication. For GitHub, get a [personal access token](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line) and set `access_token` as follows:

```
resource "aws_amplify_app" "nextjs_app" {
  name     = "nextjs_app_amplify"
  platform = "WEB"
  repository = "https://github.com/xxx/nectjs-example.git"

  # GitHub personal access token
  access_token = "..."
}
```

You can omit access_token if you import an existing Amplify App created by the Amplify Console (using OAuth for authentication).

*Source: [Terraform aws_amplyfy_app documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/amplify_app#repository-with-tokens)*